# HttpReponseMessage has StatusCode 200 but 'Result' is empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, async-await, bigcommerce

I am currently developing an application that integrates with a Web API. I have an async function which sends a `PUT` request to the Web API in order to update a product.

```
    public async Task<ResponseStatus> updateProduct(Item product)
    {
        string URL = client.BaseAddress + "/catalog/products/" + product.id;
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PutAsJsonAsync(URL, product).ConfigureAwait(false);
        var payload = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        ResponseStatus res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseStatus>(await payload.ConfigureAwait(false));

        return res;
    }
```

In a Console App I am using to test my application this function works exactly as intended and I receive the updated product as a JSON String in the `Result` of the Response.

[image]

However when I attempt to call this function from an ASP.Net application, I receive an empty string in the `Result`, even though it has a status code of 200. I can also see that my update has not taken effect on the product, even though it definitely updates when called in the Console Application.

[image]

There are a few Web API calls that I have such as this `GET` request, that works in almost exactly the same way, except this works in the ASP.Net application AND the test Console App.

```
    public async Task<Product> getProductByID(int id)
    {
        Product product = null;
        string URL = client.BaseAddress + "/catalog/products/" + id;
        string additionalQuery = "include=images,variants";
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(URL + "?" + additionalQuery).ConfigureAwait(false);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var payload = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            product = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Product>(await payload.ConfigureAwait(false));
        }
        return product;
    }
```

Why in the ASP.Net app do I receive a Success Status Code even though the `Result` is empty and the update to the product is not actually made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone coming across this. I was attempting to update a product via the BigCommerce API, and I had an error in my code where the `custom_url` object of the product had it's URL set to `null`.

[image]

This was obviously producing an error on the BigCommerce API server but it can't be getting handled correctly as a Success Code 200 was being returned, even though the Product was not getting updated. This was producing the empty response I was getting.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `await` the `payload Task` without `ConfigureAwait(false)`.

By using `ConfigureAwait(false)` you are not guaranteed to keep the ASP.NET response context when the `Task` returns the `Result`. This is a peculiarity to the ASP.NET runtime.

It's mentioned as a [Best Practice tip for async/await by Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx):

> You should not use ConfigureAwait when you have code after the await in the method that needs the context. For GUI apps, this includes any code that manipulates GUI elements, writes data-bound properties or depends on a GUI-specific type such as Dispatcher/CoreDispatcher. **For ASP.NET apps, this includes any code that uses HttpContext.Current or builds an ASP.NET response**, including return statements in controller actions.

Comment: I tried changing it to `ResponseStatus res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseStatus>(await payload);` but that unfortunately made no difference. Should I be removing the ConfigureAwait(false) from any other lines?

Comment: Potentially the line with `await client.GetAsync`

Comment: Unfortunately that means that my debugging of the application just stops after the `client.GetAsync` line is called, as per my question on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44828701/calling-asynchronous-api-in-asp-net-application) about the issue.

The `await payload.ConfigureAwaity(false)` line works correctly in the `getProductByID` function I showed in my answer so I do not think that's the issue.